# Using php loops inside mailtext [mail()]

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

I have to send an email for each order. I would formatting the Text a little bit and if there are more orders i would separate like this:
1 clothes 20eur
1 shoes 10eur...
At the moment looks like:
1, 1 clothes, shoes 20eur,10eur
This way i need a loop for separate them, but got error 'unexpected foreach'.

```
$mailtext = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form order</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form order</h1>
<p>Details:</p>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Adress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>'.$name.'</td>
  <td>'.$strase.'</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>Order:</p>
'
 foreach ($produktarr as $row){
  echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['amount'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['product'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
  echo'</tr>';
}
'
</body>
</html>

';
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XciBrKtm *EXPIRES: IN 29 DAYS, lovely*. So, once we hit the 29th day from now, your question will be useless. and that famous `$produktarr`, that's coming from where?! You could've easily have pasted that yourself in your question.

Comment: you miss ; at the end of your $mailtext variable

Comment: you've edited the expiry now. Since you have control over that pastebin, how do we know you're not going to change it down the line? Post your code in your question.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani , no it doesn´t missing.

Comment: @user5441400 true,my bad

Comment: @Fred-ii- , sorry now withouth pastebin. `$produktarr = $_POST['Produkt'];` @Nicolò Cozzani , no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a foreach loop inside a variable declaration?
I would do something like this:

```
$mailtext = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form order</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form order</h1>
<p>Details:</p>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Adress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>'.$name.'</td>
  <td>'.$strase.'</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>Order:</p>
';
 foreach ($produktarr as $row){
 $mailtext.= '<tr><td>'.$row['amount'].'</td><td>'.$row['product'].'</td><td>'.$row['price'].'</td></tr>';

}
$mailtext.= '</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: Thank you this way should work ;D.